# logDNA supertenant agent volume mounts

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure, logdna

To accommodate multiple individual services in a single OpenShift cluster, I need to deploy multiple logDNA supertenant agents for each service in its own namespace.

These individual agents would then scrape logs from sub-directories under `/var/log` for example: agent-1 scrapes logs from `/var/log/my-service-1`, similarly agent-2 scrapes logs from `/var/log/my-service-2`.

However, while configuring these agents I also need to maintain isolation between each of them due to compliance requirements. This means I do not want these agents to unnecessarily share volumes, which I came across [here](https://github.com/logdna/logdna-agent-v2/blob/bbafbb058f6936a43969e38bfc2fbf49f053e353/k8s/agent-resources-openshift-supertenant.yaml#L165) while defining the agent yaml.

Please advise on why we need the below mentioned volumes and which I could drop from my configuration.

```yaml
        - name: varlog
          hostPath:
            path: /var/log
        - name: vardata
          hostPath:
            path: /var/data
        - name: varliblogdna
          hostPath:
            path: /var/lib/logdna
        - name: varlibdockercontainers
          hostPath:
            path: /var/lib/docker/containers
        - name: mnt
          hostPath:
            path: /mnt
        - name: osrelease
          hostPath:
            path: /etc/os-release
        - name: logdnahostname
          hostPath:
            path: /etc/hostname
```

I understand for configuring `lookback` in the agent I need the `/var/lib/logdna` volume but not particularly sure on the other volumes. I specifically feel like I could drop the `/var/data` and `/var/lib/docker/containers` as these shared directories between the deployed cluster services and need not be mounted for compliance sake.

Comment: UPDATE:

The agent configuration works fine with just the two below-mentioned mounts as well. Should I still consider using other volumes as well?

```yaml
      volumes:
        - name: varlog
          hostPath:
            path: /var/log/myservice
            type: ''
        - name: varliblogdna
          hostPath:
            path: /var/lib/logdna
            type: ''
```